# Add a Date in Linq to Entities

Tags: entity-framework

With Linq to Entities, I am trying to query a Log table to find rows near a matching row. I am having trouble with adding a date inside the query. This is what I have so far.

```
from
    l in objectSet.Logs
let
    match = objectSet.Logs.Where(whatever).FirstOrDefault()
where
       l.Timestamp > (match.Timestamp - twoHours)
    && l.Timestamp < (match.Timestamp + twoHours)
select
    l
```

Leaving out the "whatever" condition that finds the row I'm interested in, "twoHours" has variably been a time span, a `.AddHours()` function and so forth. I haven't found the right way that EF can generate SQL that adds the value from a field (match.Timestamp) to a constant.

The obvious solution is to do the "match" query first and then use the literal value in a second query, but I have simplified the code example here to the main problem (adding dates in the query) and in actual fact my query is more complex and this would not be ideal.

Cheers

Comment: I have had a similar issue. The problem is that .AddHours() does not have a SQL equivalent, and thus, Linq is unable to convert that to a SQL expression. I have overcome this by invoking the delayed execution by calling .ToList() and then applying your .AddHours() filter on an in-memory collection.

Comment: @XSaint32, that's doubly wrong. There *is* [a (T)SQL equivalent,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and you *can* call it from the EF.

Comment: @Craig - Thanks for the input. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can generate an `AddHours` using the `EntityFunctions` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx).

```
from
    l in objectSet.Logs
let
    match = objectSet.Logs.Where(whatever).FirstOrDefault()
where
       (l.Timestamp > EntityFunctions.AddHours(match.Timestamp, -1 * twoHours))
    && // ...
select
    l
```

**However**, don't expect this `WHERE` to be optimized with an index unless you have an expression index on the column.

Comment: Note, `EntityFunctions` has been marked as obsolete. Use the replacement class `DbFunctions` in namespace `System.Data.Entity` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`EntityFunctions` is deprecated in favor of `DbFunctions`

```
public int GetNumUsersByDay(DateTime Date)
        {
            using (var context = db)
            {
                var DateDay = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, Date.Day);
                var DateDayTomorrow = DateDay.AddDays(1);
                return context.Users.Where(m => DbFunctions.AddHours(m.DateCreated,-5) >= DateDay && m.DateCreated < DateDayTomorrow).Count();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

As it was described in this article - http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/?p=2982#first, use parameters (declare variable) instead of DateTime using in your queries.